# Need help in SQL query to get the no of records based on id's

Tags: sql

If the table is as below

```
id  skill
1   Java
1   C  
1   SQL
2   Java
3   .Net
3   Hadoop
```

```sql
Select * from table_name where rownum < 10
```

It will get the 10 records in the table. But I want 10 id’s records from the table.

Expected Output is :
If i say condtion 2 id records then output must be

```
id  skill
1   Java
1   C
1   SQL
2   Java
```

I want condition based on id's not on rownum count..

Thanks for your help Got soolution in MSQL

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN ( SELECT distinct top(2) id from table_name )
Result is :
1   Java
1   C
1   SQL
2   Java

Comment: Do you want to get records for 10 different ids?

Comment: Question is not clear , modify it plz

Comment: @user3143363 - please add your expected result too

Comment: What db engine are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: As per current question select id instead of *  ,  Select id from table_name where rownum < 10

Comment: if i say condition as 2 i want 
1   Java
1   C  
1   SQL
2   Java
-----2 id's data .. DB is oracle..

Comment: Yes @AkshatSinghal .. i want 10 different id's record

Answer (score 1):

select * from table_name where id <= 10

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not at all clear, but if you really `want 10 id’s records from the table` then do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 DISTINCT id from table_name
```

If not, clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE id IN (  SELECT  id from table_name 
               WHERE id <= 10 )`